# ArcSDE 10.2: How to enable and create Geodatabase in Oracle without ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

Since there is no Post Installation Wizard anymore in ArcSDE 10.2 - how can i enable und create a geodatabase in oracle without ArcGIS Desktop? We have only an EDN description for ArcGIS Server/SDE, but no desktop license.

Is there any documentation about it?

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows Service

> You can create and register an ArcSDE service on Windows servers from
>   an MS-DOS prompt using the sdeservice command.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcsde-application-server-oracle/10.2/index.html#/Creating_an_ArcSDE_service_on_Windows_using_the_sdeservice_command/00940000006w000000/

**For creating the geodatabasase** (after users/roles are set) python is required.
Scripting geodatabase creation in Oracle

> Install and configure Oracle on your server. If you will be running
>   the Python script from a different computer than the Oracle server,
>   install the Oracle client on the computer from which you will run the
>   script.
>
> The Oracle client can be downloaded from the Esri Customer Care
>   Portal. If you will be running the script from an ArcGIS 32-bit
>   client, download the 32-bit version of the Oracle client. If you will
>   be running the script from ArcGIS for Server, download the 64-bit
>   version of the Oracle client. See Setting up a connection to Oracle
>   for more information. Copy one of these example scripts to the Python
>   window in ArcGIS for Desktop or to any Python IDE, such as PythonWin
>   or WING, on a computer where ArcGIS for Desktop (Standard or
>   Advanced), ArcGIS for Server (Standard or Advanced), or ArcGIS Engine
>   with the Geodatabase Update extension is installed.
>
> This example creates an sde user and tablespace, grants the sde user
>   privileges to create a geodatabase, then creates the geodatabase:

code available at:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Scripting_geodatabase_creation_in_Oracle/002n000000t8000000/

Comment: thx for your quick response. but i have to say - this became way more complecated than with the post installation wizard in previous versions.